# php: When ReflectionMethod returns error, how do I find out where a function is defined

Tags: php, debugging, joomla

```
$this->config = ED::config();
$this->jconfig = ED::jconfig();
$this->doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$this->app = JFactory::getApplication();
$this->input = ED::request();
$this->theme = ED::themes();

$method = new ReflectionMethod('ED', 'themes'); // Getting error message: 0 Method ED::themes() does not exist
```

This is inside a Joomla webs application. I was trying to find out where `ED::themes()` is defined. I was able to find the file that defines class `ED`, however, there is no static function `themes` in that file. So I have tried to user ReflectionMethod, however it returns an error message saying `ED::themes()` doesn't exists. So I am stuck here. How can I find out where this `ED::themes()` is defined?

Comment: @Sharky could have answered this one in JSE, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class in question has `__callStatic` [magic method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) which handles the calls to non-existing static methods like `themes()`. Unless available methods are documented by the developer of the class, you'll have to examine `__callStatic` method yourself to figure out what ends up being called.